# MySQL Outperforming Redis

Tags: mysql, redis, benchmarking

I'm trying to make a script of benchmarks for a mysql operation vs a redis operation.

Here is what I've tried:

```
1./ List of comment ids with a separate hash of comment JSON Data mapped to comment id

2./ List of comments json data

3./ Sorted set of comments with ranking and json data as mapped value
```

For some reason, mysql keeps out performing redis and I dont understand why. **Im querying 100 records.**

Here are my operations (separated by attempts):

```
1./ $client->rpush($commentId); $client->hmset($commentId,$data);

2./ $client->rpush($jsonData);

3./ $client->zadd("comments",$i,$jsonData);
```

Here's my benchmark script:

```
$client = new Predis\Client($conf);
$st=microtime(true);
// sorted set solution
$dat=$client->zrange("comments",0,100);
// list solution
//$dat=$client->lrange("comments",0,100);
$ft=microtime(true);
$overall=$ft-$st;
echo "REDIS=>".$overall."\n";

$sta=microtime(true);
$st=mysqli_query($dbh,"select SQL_NO_CACHE * from comments where status>0 order by createdate desc limit 0,100");
while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($st)){
  $dd=$r;
}
$fta=microtime(true);
$overall=$fta-$sta;
echo "MYSQL=>".$overall."\n";
```

Here is my redis store script for sorted sets:

```
$st=mysqli_query($dbh,"select SQL_NO_CACHE * from comments where status>0 order by createdate desc LIMIT 100");
$i=1;
while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($st)){
  $client->zadd("comments",$i,json_encode($r));
  $i++;
}
```

Here is my redis store script for list:

```
$st=mysqli_query($dbh,"select SQL_NO_CACHE * from comments where status>0 order by createdate desc LIMIT 100");
$i=1;
while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($st)){
  $key="comment:$id";
  $client->rpush("comments",$key);
  foreach($r as $k=>$v){
   $client->hset($key,$k,$v);
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Here is my redis store script for list without pointing hash:

```
$st=mysqli_query($dbh,"select SQL_NO_CACHE * from comments where status>0 order by createdate desc LIMIT 100");
$i=1;
while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($st)){
  $key="comment:$id";
  $client->rpush("comments",json_encode($r));
}
```

Here is the DB Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `commentid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parentid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `refno` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `createdate` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `remoteip` varchar(80) DEFAULT '',
  `fingerprint` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `locid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `clubid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `profileid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `userid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `global` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `official` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `legacyuser` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `mediaid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `comment` varchar(4000) DEFAULT '',
  `likes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `dislikes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `import` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `author` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`commentid`),
  KEY `comments_locid` (`locid`),
  KEY `comments_userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `idx_legacyusers` (`legacyuser`),
  KEY `profile_index` (`profileid`),
  KEY `comments_createdate` (`createdate`),
  KEY `compound_for_comments` (`locid`,`global`,`status`),
  KEY `global` (`global`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `locid_status` (`locid`,`status`),
  KEY `global_status` (`global`,`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

**We are using Redislabs as our redis server.**

If I'm missing anything to make this a valid question please let me know.

Comment: We can't evaluate your tests if you don't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How about now @Dinei

Comment: What is your question? If you're talking about straight selects out of MySQL vs. fetching from Redis... I'm not surprised. The value of redis comes into play when storing more computationally intense calculations that need to happen again and again.

Comment: Im not understanding then why we are wasting our time with redis as a cache backend. I was under the impression switching from a mysql backend to a redis in memory solution was the approach we were told to take.

Comment: MySQL stores data in memory too, in the InnoDB buffer pool. If you run simple SQL queries (like query one row by its primary key) against data that is already in the buffer pool, it's very fast.

Comment: Still not enough @jkushner. Is this a PHP script? How are you measuring time? What are your DB schema? What SQL command are you using? What are the hardware and software specifications? Benchmarks are hard, and if your MySQL in HD is faster than Redis in memory you certainly have some problem in your method.

Comment: @Dinei Look at update

Comment: @BillKarwin What about querying 100 records? I was under the impression Redis comes into play when at this count of records to query.

Comment: @Dinei see updates now

Comment: Do you have the MySQL query cache enabled? That could make queries return in a fraction of the time they take to really execute. But this is not a good thing for benchmarking because it distorts your results. You can suppress use of the query cache by making your queries like `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`. You should disable the query cache. It is deprecated in MySQL 5.7, and it has been removed from MySQL 8.0. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html

Comment: @BillKarwin Mysql is still beating Redis with disabling Query Cache,

Comment: You said you're using redislabs. I guess this is a cloud-hosted redis instance? Are you comparing that to a local MySQL instance? Perhaps it's network round-trip latency that is making the cloud redis appear slow.

Comment: @BillKarwin Redislabs connects to an Amazon Redis Service. This is actually a good test.

Comment: @BillKarwin Seems to have been the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on above comments, the network latency of the remote Redis instance hosted in AWS was greater than the latency of a local MySQL instance.

Naturally, when you add 40-100ms of latency to every Redis request (depending on how far across the internet your app is from the hosted Redis), it makes Redis appear slower in terms of total request time.

Comment: Correct. Thanks.